# Ignore primary key duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

I have an array of almost 5000 objects I am entering into a MySQL database.

The array has an index 'crn', and the corresponding column in the MySQL table is the primary key.

Is there any way I can tell mysql to skip an entry if it detects a duplicate primary key rather than stop execution of the script?

I could check the table before insertion of each row, but since i'm only expecting 1 or 2 duplicates among the 5000 or so objects, it seems it would turn out to be very expensive.

Comment: How can you insert a row having duplicate primary key first of all ?

Comment: @BigFatPig: that's the point. I don't want to insert it. If it collides, just ignore it (i.e. skip insertion for that row)

Comment: how do you insert objects ? what language for script do you use?

Comment: forgot to tag it php. I'm using a php running from php-cgi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `INSERT IGNORE` instead of just `INSERT`

Comment: Will this `ignore` the duplicate primary key and force insertion, or will this skip insertion?

Comment: And if you want to update if a duplicate is found you can run `INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES (1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value)`

Comment: perfect. That's just what I want.

Comment: If you want to completely _replace_ the old record with the new one (in contrast to just update the old one, like Geoffrey mentioned) use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

As @KingCrunch stated, INSERT IGNORE can do that for you.

If you however need to know about the duplicates, you might want to consider INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html